# Failed to output video file by OpenCV on MacOS with C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, video

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){

    VideoCapture vcap("0");
    if(!vcap.isOpened()){
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int frame_width=   vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frame_height=   vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    VideoWriter video("~/out.avi", CV_FOURCC('J','P','E','G'), 10, Size(frame_width,frame_height),true);

    for(;;){
        Mat frame;
        vcap >> frame;
        video << frame;
        imshow( "Frame", frame );
        char c = (char)waitKey(33);
        if( c == 'q' ) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the above code, the program can correctly show the camera image through imshow(), but after terminate the program, no video output file has written to the disk. I use MacOS Xcode and OpenCV 2.4.13 as development platform. The same work and output the video file completely on Windows Visual Studio. Please help.

Comment: What's the return value of `cv::VideoWriter::isOpened()`?

Comment: I tried something like this on Fedora 24 with OpenCV 2.4.12.  I think there might be a hang up with "~/out.avi".  Try specifying a path without the tilde.